# How to specify requirements for Office (Word + Excel) Addin?

Tags: office-js, office-store

We have an Addin that can run on Word and Excel, but I want to limit it only to specific platforms (Word 2016 or greater, Excel 2016 or greater). How can I do it using Manifest file?

Currently I am trying to limit like that:

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set name="WordApi" />
        <Set name="ExcelApi" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements
```

But when I upload this manifest to Seller Dashboard, i get the following:

> Please make sure that the file is an Office package manifest

What I am doing wrong? Sorry, but it's not clear from the documentation how to specify host requirements

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you define `Requirements` in your manifest, you are telling Office that it should only surface your Add-in when *all* off the Requirments have been met.

Since you're requiring both `WordApi` and `ExcelApi`, your add-in will only show up if the Office Application supports *both* of these. Since there isn't an Office Application that supports both, your Add-in simply won't show up.

At the moment, the only way to support both `WordApi` and `ExcelApi` in your Add-in is to have two distinct manifests; one for Word and another for Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What does it mean "two manifests"? I need to create two separate apps - one for Word and one for Excel? Or what are the other ways to add Addin, that works in Word and Excel in the Office Store?

Comment: It can be the same app/code, you just need two `manifest.xml` files; one for Word and another for Excel. When submitting to the Store, I'd recommend sticking with the single manifest and following Office Store Developer Comms' instructions. They are _the_ definitive source when it comes to AppSource after all.

Answer (score 0):

If your manifest contains Word API (or any host specific API) then it will not show up in other clients. 
If your add-in is designed to work in multiple clients, and requires an API not currently supported in Office 2013, please include these details in the test notes of your next submission. Should the validation team need any additional information to resolve the issue, they will reachout to you at the email address on record to discuss how to proceed.

All apps and add-ins submitted to the Office Store must comply with the Office Store Validation Policies
Specifically section [4.12.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies), "Your add-in must work across all platforms that support the methods that you define in the Requirements element in your add-in manifest." For details about which platforms support which methods, see [Office Add-in host and platform availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Please correct me if I am wrong. I need to remove all Requirements from manifest and specify in the Test Notes, that my app works only in Word/Excel 2016 or greater?

Comment: I would suggest _explicitly_ stating that requires `WordAPI v1.1` for Word hosts and `ExcelAPI v1.1` for Excel hosts. "Word 2016" isn't accurate since your Add-in would work anywhere the API is supported (Word for Windows 2016,  Word Online, Word for iPad, etc).  I would also suggest providing the link to your question here for reference.

Comment: Hi, this is what I've got after following your advice: 

`Your add-in is not working in the Word/ Excel 2013
client on Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 11.
When we inserted your add-in and launched it, we
could immediately see a message in your add-in
that the code requires Word 2016 or greater.
If you do not support 2013 SP1 because you are
using an API only available in 2016/Online, you
must put these apis in the requirements tag in your
manifest.
If you are not using an API only available in
2016/Online, then you must support 2013 SP1`

Comment: Hi Alexey, The team reached out to you via email to assist you in getting your add-in published.